# Unable to access CentOS 7 Postgresql Server from another CentOS7 using PHP and PDO

Tags: centos, php, postgresql, centos7, selinux

### The Beginning

**Server 1** is my CentOS 7 production server. It contains Apache, ssh and a Postgresql database.

**Server 2** is my CentOS 7 test server. It contains Apache, ssh and a test database.

Both servers are set with firewalld to accept 22, 80 and 443.
Both servers have the following setting.

`sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`
...

### How do I know these ports are open?

I can ssh in (port 22). I can see the "Testing 1, 2, 3..." test page via http and https (port 80 and 443). I can access Postgresql by using SQL Maestro, DBeaver, DBSchema, etc. (port 5432).

...

### The Problem

I can access Postgresql on **Server 1** using DbSchema, HeidiSQL, Postgresql SQL Maestro, etc, remotely, from anywhere. However, I cannot connect from **Server 2** using PHP and PDO. It always leads to ***[08006] Timeout***.

I tried the following, but did not help;
sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1

...

### The Question

How do I access Postgresql db on **Server 1** from **Server 2** using PHP? I'm new to CentOS7. I have done this before using other Linux distro with no issues. What SELinux/other settings that I missing?
...

### The Solution (below)

See Alexander's answer below. I thought the 5432 was enabled in firewall-cmd.
When I issued the following command

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-services
```

only `dhcpv6-client http ssh https` were listed! What happened to my postgresql?
I simply issued the following to make the service permanent;

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql --permanent
```

Comment: That looks like a firewall issue, not an SELinux issue. Check your firewalls.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, what rule am I specifically looking at? Firewalld or the company's firewall?

Comment: You need to look at every relevant firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, all right. I'm on it. I will post an update.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, +1 you were right, it is not an SELinux issue. I tried to switch it off, and did not solve the problem. I'm still looking in to firewall.

Comment: Disabling Server 1's FirewallD works! But I don't like disabling firewalld.

Comment: You could just open the port.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, 80, 443 and 5432 are open. I'll just leave it here for now. My knowledge in firewallD is not even knee-deep. Disabling firewalld on my production server is a no-no. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: How do you know that those ports are open? Why haven't you added this information to your question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, because I can access Postgresql on Server 1 using DbSchema, HeidiSQL, Postgresql SQL Maestro, etc, remotely, from anywhere, and I can see "Testing 123..." httpd testing page. I'm sorry about that. It is added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in you question, you have opened only three ports in firewalld. You should open port 5432 on firewall.

Also you should check on which IP listening postgres, it could listening only on 127.0.0.1:5432.

Comment: I thought 5432 was opened... but... double checked... not there.. maybe I didn't specify --permanent. I accepted your answer.